# Failing to install tensorrt on Jetson Linux using pip

Tags: python, linux, pip, nvidia, tensorrt

**Description**
When I try to install tensorrt using pip in a python virtual environment, the setup fails and gives the following error:
ERROR: Failed building wheel for tensorrt.

**Possible solutions tried**
I have upgraded the version of the pip but it still doesn’t work.

**Environment**
TensorRT Version: 8.5
CUDA Version: 11.4
CUDNN Version: 8.6
Operating System + Version: Jetson 35.2
Python Version (if applicable): 3.8

Answer (score 0):

If you have Jetpack installed on your Jetson, you could use `apt-get` to install Python's `tensorrt` module.

On my Jetson Xavier NX with Jetpack installed

```bash
$ python3 -c "import tensorrt as trt; print(trt.__path__)"
['/usr/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tensorrt']
$ dpkg -S /usr/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tensorrt
python3-libnvinfer: /usr/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tensorrt
```

So you should install `python3-libnvinfer` to get `tensorrt` module in Python.

```bash
apt-get install python3-libnvinfer
```